# PKM R/B: experience underflow and Ditto glitch

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

I've ended my Pokémon blue game and I'm now trying to have fun exploiting a few glitches. I want to catch a L1 Nidoking to then be able to exploit the experience underflow and bring it to L100 after its first battle.

To catch it I am using a L3 Pidgey with a special stat of 7. I am triggering the glitch using a trainer at the left of Lavander Town. I step towards him and while he notices me I fly to Fuchsia City. I then battle a trainer at the left of the city (making him come to me) and then head over the right of the city where there are patches of grass where Ditto can be caught. I encounter it (L26) and make it transform into my L3 Pidgey. The issue isn't that when I try to use Growl, I can only do it 5 times before getting the "Nothing happens" message. I can't do it 6 times. I tried with other Ditto encounters but it's always 5 Growls max.
Do you know why? What causes then number of Growls that have an effect? Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking. In pokemon, if you use a stat-decreasing move enough times on one pokemon, the move will stop affecting the enemy pokemon. There is no way to lower its stat any more than 6 growls.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I meant that I can only Growl 5 times (not 6), making the pokemon that appears because of the bug a L2 instead of L1

Comment: IIRC the glitch is based on your pokemon's PP, which is lowered even if the move has no effect.